# Grabbing personal data from BitFinex using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've seen here how I can grab data from Bitfinex, 
but what I want to ask is:
Is there a possibility to grab personal data from bitfinex, considering the login process + google authenticator?
I guess what I'm asking is: is it even possible to get the quantity of a certain crypto in an account and the last price (the last price isn't the personal part obviously- this I do know how to grab)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do a search on github... Plenty of bitfinex + python code

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.